# Why do different mousemove events have the same XY coordinates?

Tags: javascript

I am tracking and logging the cursor position on the mousemove event using `.pageX` and `.pageY`, and I've noticed that some of the events are fired with the same xy coordinates. What am I missing here? Is there a better way to get real time cursor coordinates?

```js
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  console.log("x:", e.pageX, "y:", e.pageY);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Log Coordinates</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my browser's console, the duplicates are shown in by the number to the left of the log (3, 5, 3, 5, etc...), as the console has collapsed the duplicate logs into one line.

Here is a screenshot of the output of the above stack snippet:

[image: duplicate mousemove events]

Comment: I am not seing any duplicates in firefox or chrome. Which browser is this?

Comment: When your code log X position as 307 and Y position as 284, then X:308 and Y:284, then X:309 and Y:284, it simply means your mouse is perfectly align with the same Y axis as it moves slightly along the X axis while moving and logging position. The outcome is indeed accurate.